# Is it possible to run a jquery plugin like masonry or isotope on a single page in a Joomla website?

Tags: jquery, joomla, content-management-system, jquery-masonry

The question pretty much says it all. I have a joomla website and I want to create a video gallery using Masonry or Isotope. Is it possible and if so how is it done?

Comment: You must show us your effort. Show us some scripts.

Comment: I'm a complete novice at this so I have no script to show. I'm using a generic template I downloaded and have edited myself and use Joomla as my CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

1. Define new module position.
2. Define new menu item that links to a desired page.
3. Create custom module and assign it to that postion. Set the module to be displayed only for this particular module item.
4. Edit your template adding code like this:

   if (mosCountModules ('my_custom_position')) { 
   HERE LOAD ISOTOPE/MASONRY FILES AND INIT THE LAYOUT
   }
5. You are done!

Answer (score 2):

If you embed the isotope / masonry scripts in your template or on that particular page, it should just work, if you set it up with the right HTML / CSS / JS.

Answer (score 1):

To run scripts on a page, simple add this code to the top of the plugin php file

```
$document->addScript(JURI::root() . "plugins/plg_yourplugin/script.js");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this module for Joomla created with Isotope
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-showcase/20706

Comment: There is may way to create like this module... Dont try to download it before trying :)